Express Static File Serve
I am a bit stuck while trying to serve my static files. I tried couple of methods that are shared here and there but none worked for me.
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'css')));

My folder structure looks like this
v4-----Project Folder
 app.js
 public---Public Folder
  css
   main.css

And I am trying to access it via the URL below:
http://localhost:3000/main.css

I tried to add pseudo root such as
app.use('/css', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'css')));

http://localhost:3000/css/main.css

and tried many combinations, i am sure that express.static receives a valid path but there's sth wrong with the serving.
Can you help me to identify problem?
I appreciate your support in advance.

Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Consider editing your question so that it attracts people to look into it and try to answer. The structure can be improved with inbuilt writing tools.

What exactly is going wrong? Are you getting any error?

hello, no actually, all i can spot is when i try to access it with url, it redirects to 404 page i created and i also add the css file to certain pages but their styling also not working

@sinemşahan What you said about 404 should've been presented in the question. Please, provide a way to reproduce, e.g. a repo. Currently the problem is not reproducible, what you do is correct and should work the way you describe

So, seems like I misinterpret the location of my middlewares which read my html and css data before serving the static files, resulting this failure. I appreciate your responses to my first question.
